# Expand a tiny URL to a full URL with redirection in Apache

Tags: apache-http-server, http, url

I have an application setup for expanding a tiny URL. Once a hit is received from the browser, it will create a request in my Apache load balancer running on my domain. Let's assume my domain is "mydomain".

When the request comes to my Apache load balancer it should be translated to the URL: `http://ip:port/MY_APP/myAdaptor/abcd`

Tiny URL: `http://mydomain.le/abcd`

Expanded URL: `http://ip:port/MY_APP/myAdaptor/abcd`

The parameters are:

- `IP`: IP of the server
- `port`: port of the application
- `MY_APP`: my deployed application
- `myAdaptor`: my adaptor name
- `abcd`: tiny URL

How can I configure this?

Comment: Hi, when I am hitting to http://mydomain.le/abcd this URL, I can reach up to http://ip:port/MY_APP/myAdaptor, but I need http://ip:port/MY_APP/myAdaptor/abcd. How I can achieve this

Comment: We still don't know anything about your setup. What tools are you using? How are they configured currently? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: The request is landing to apache load balancer, in workers.properties  worker.APPSERVER1.port=16009
worker.APPSERVER1.host=10.0.0.93
worker.APPSERVER1.type=ajp13   , i have configured my tomcat application. But tiny url value not recieving to tomcat setup.

Comment: You realise this would be a lot easier to do if you dropped ajp and did http balancing, possibly with a bit of URL rewriting thrown in, right,?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding below configuration in httpd.conf got the result as expected.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+) http://ip:port/MY_APP/myAdaptor/$1
</IfModule>
```